# How would I go about making it so that each new generation of triangles in this koch snowflake is a different color? (Python + Turtle)

Tags: python, fractals, turtle-graphics

So I have this program that generates a hexagonal koch snowflake using these two main functions:

```
def mvmt(length):

if length <= 10:
    voldemort.forward(length)
else:
    mvmt(length/3)
    voldemort.right(60)
    mvmt(length/3)
    voldemort.left(120)
    mvmt(length/3)
    voldemort.right(60)
    mvmt(length/3)


def whole(length = 300):
    voldemort.hideturtle()
    voldemort.penup()
    voldemort.goto(-300,-255)
    voldemort.pendown()
    voldemort.begin_fill()
    mvmt(length)
    voldemort.left(60)
    mvmt(length)
    voldemort.left(60)
    mvmt(length)
    voldemort.left(60)
    mvmt(length)
    voldemort.left(60)
    mvmt(length)
    voldemort.left(60)
    mvmt(length)
    voldemort.end_fill()
```

How do I make it so that each new set of triangles added through the iterative process is a new color?

I'd rather not use meticulous processes of changing the fill color, then running "voldemort.beginfill()" and "voldemort.endfill()". Help is highly appreciated. *NOTE* This is written in python using the Turtle Module.

Comment: you can use `beginfill()` and `endfill()` but you have to paint the triangle first and then do recursion. This should not be a problem since you know how to paint it. You can set the velocity of the turtle to first paint the edges slowly and then instantly fill the triangle.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. I was able to get the outermost (smallest) set of triangles to be filled black by running the fill commands inside of the "mvmt()" function. The others will not fill. Could you elaborate please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to clone the turtle inside `mvmt()`, so you have an independent one that you can fill without interfering with the filling of the outer one.

To make that work recursively, you have to pass the current turtle as a parameter to `mvmt()`.

That's what I changed your code to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import division

import colorsys
import turtle

def mvmt(original, length):
    if length >= 10:
        fraction = length / 3
        h, s, v = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(*original.fillcolor())

        clone = original.clone()
        clone.fillcolor(colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(h + 1/6, s, v))
        clone.begin_fill()
        mvmt(clone, fraction)
        clone.right(60)
        mvmt(clone, fraction)
        clone.left(120)
        mvmt(clone, fraction)
        clone.right(60)
        mvmt(clone, fraction)
        clone.end_fill()

    original.forward(length)

def whole(length = 300):
    voldemort = turtle.Turtle()
    voldemort.speed(0)
    voldemort.hideturtle()
    voldemort.penup()
    voldemort.goto(-200,-255)
    voldemort.pendown()

    voldemort.fillcolor((1.0, 0.5, 0.5))
    voldemort.begin_fill()
    mvmt(voldemort, length)
    voldemort.left(60)
    mvmt(voldemort, length)
    voldemort.left(60)
    mvmt(voldemort, length)
    voldemort.left(60)
    mvmt(voldemort, length)
    voldemort.left(60)
    mvmt(voldemort, length)
    voldemort.left(60)
    mvmt(voldemort, length)
    voldemort.end_fill()

turtle.delay(0)
turtle.speed(0)

whole()
turtle.exitonclick()
```